# Huawei E1550 not detected

Tags: usb-modem, huawei

my Huawei E1550 (which previously worked OK) is not detected. In order to get it to work, I used codeswitch successfully.

The blue light (or green depending on coverage) pulses OK but my machine appears not to see it at all.

Here's lsusb output with it plugged in:

```
nick@nick-laptop:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here's lsusb with nothing plugged in:

```
nick@nick-laptop:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here's lsusb with a sandisk usb memory stick plugged in (to show usb port is OK):

```
nick@nick-laptop:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0781:5151 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Micro Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: are you sure your device is ok now? test it other system.

Answer (score 1):

If your device is okay on other computers and if it is a laptop, try using other USB ports. and if possible try using it connected to AC power. This seems like a power issue to me :)

Comment: Agree with the USB thing. The best way is to try on another system.

Comment: OK - thanks for the suggestions. I've tried it on a desktop linux box too - and lsusb doesn't see it. Maybe hardware is faulty.